# Accessing db fields at run time

Tags: django-models

I have a dict like this :

```
my_dict = {'B01' : 23, 'B03': 35, 'B26' : 102} #Bnn between B01 and B30
```

I have a django model like this :

```
class my_model(models.Model):
    Bin_01 = models.IntegerField()
    Bin_02 = models.IntegerField()
    #.....
    Bin_30 = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to write code somewhat like this :

```
my_record = my_model()
for k in my_dict.keys:
    fieldName = 'Bin_' + k[1:2]
    my_record.fieldName = my_dict[k]
```

I know "my_record *.fieldName*" won't work.

How do I acheive this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**exec** function be used as:

`for key,value in my_dict.items():
        fieldName = 'Bin_' + key[1:3]
        exec("my_record." + fieldName + "=value")`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.
Hope this will not have any performance issues